# Get item with max score React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have data that returning from BE

Here is code where I show it

```
<div className="pr-0 mt-20" style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <MuiCardWithAnimation component={AnimateSimple} recipe="slideRightInLarge" className="w-6/12  mx-auto m-16 md:m-0" square>
        <CardContent className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center p-32 md:p-48 md:pt-128 ">
          <Typography variant="h6" className="md:w-full mb-32">
            Result
          </Typography>

          {companiesHouseResults?.filter(r => Math.max(r.matchConfidenceScore)).map((r) => (
            <div className="col col-lg-4 grid-wrapper">
              <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
                    Company Name: {r.companyName}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography sx={{ mb: 1.5 }}>Confidence Band: {r.matchConfidenceBand}</Typography>
                  <Typography variant="body2">Confidence Score: {r.matchConfidenceScore}</Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </div>
          ))}
        </CardContent>
      </MuiCardWithAnimation>
    </div>
```

Here  `{companiesHouseResults?.filter(r => Math.max(r.matchConfidenceScore)).map((r)` I need to filter it to get element with highest score

But at `Math.max` I got this error

> Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if it is undefined before passing it to Math.max function, you can do it for example like this

```
r.matchConfidenceScore && Math.max(r.matchConfidenceScore)
```

Value of r.matchConfidenceScore will be cast to boolean, and if it is false it will not execute the next statement because of the logical AND (&&)

Answer (score 1):

You can [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) your items by the score and got first one.

```
const el = companiesHouseResults.sort(
  (a, b) => a.matchConfidenceScore - b.matchConfidenceScore
)[0];
```